# My shoes got swapped with someone

Tags: word-usage, usage

I had taken off my shoes(we're supposed to take them off before we enter the music room). When I came back and put them back on, I realized they weren't mine. (There had been a lot of shoes there, now only this one pair was left, so I assumed that they were mine; our shoes are black)

> Looks like my shoes got swapped with someone.
>
> My shoes got swapped with someone.

I know that "swap" sounds natural when the trade is intentional, but does it sound fine if it happens by accident?

This happened at my school. We have similar shoes, it's part of our uniform.

Comment: Your shoes did not get swapped with someone. Your shoes got swapped with someone else's, or you swapped your shoes with someone, or someone swapped shoes with you.

Comment: @Davo "You swapped your shoes with someone else's" implies that it was intentional. "It looks like my shoes got swapped with someone else's" or "Someone else has accidentally taken my shoes" would be better.

Comment: Hopefully, you realized you were wearing a person on your feet before putting your weight on her or him!